# Passing token as GET variable

Tags: php

I have a Token class and method for getting and checking tokens.

If I spit out a new token as part of a link:

```
<td><a href="users.php?delete=<?=$user['id'].'&token='.Token::generate();?>
```

Here's the function in the class:

```
  public static function generate(){
    return $_SESSION['token'] = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
  }
```

If just down below that table I echo out $_SESSION['token'] it displays a completely different token to the one in the link. I'm confused.

EDIT: here's the entire part of the page, showing the initial token creation and echo:

```
<td><a href="users.php?delete=<?=$user['id'].'&token='.Token::generate();?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-default<?=(($user['id'] == $user_data['id'])?' disabled':'');?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="delete user"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"</a></td>
            <td><?=$user['full_name'];?></td>
            <td><?=$user['email'];?></td>
            <td><?=clean_date($user['join_date']);?></td>
            <td><?php
                    if (new DateTime($user['last_login']) < new DateTime("2015-05-15 16:00:00")) {
                        echo 'Never';
                    } else {
                        echo clean_date($user['last_login']);
                    };?></td>
            <td><?=$user['permissions'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile ;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?=$_SESSION['token'];?>
```

And [here's a screenshot showing the two values are completely different](http://abload.de/img/untitled51s0o.png)

Comment: We'll need to see more code.

Comment: you might be calling `generate` somewhere else too.

Comment: @Flosculus see my edit

Comment: You're calling `generate` in a while loop.  So on every iteration, the session is being overwritten.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm a massive moron. Thankyou for that...and sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're trying to create a generate once singleton, i.e. a value that is generated once, then re-assessed in the same way.

Try this:

```
class Token
{
    public static function generate(){
        static $token;

        if (null === $token) {
            $_SESSION['token'] = $token = unpack('H*', openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32))[1];
        }

        return $token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be working only randomly. I wonder if this is a problem with base64 encoding? Perhaps sometimes there are illegal characters in the token that don't go through to GET?

Comment: @daninthemix Well, if `base64_encode` doesn't work, try `unpack('H*', openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32))[1];`

Comment: @daninthemix Or just `urlencode`, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I just needed to replace all the + signs in the generated token:

```
$token = str_replace('+','p',$token);
```

EDIT: this is even better:

```
return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($token), '+/', '-_'), '=');
```